# Activate object/file for sequential command line calls to be directed towards that object/file (Python)

Tags: python, class, console

I'm doing a console Budget Application that stores data in JSON. I've made several different commands through argparse which I'm very glad about, however, I would like to not be able to express each time what budget (if the person has several different) that the sequential adds, subtracts or edits will be towards.

Is there a way to 'activate' an object, like you do with virtual environments, so that each sequential call during that period will be towards this specific Budget json file?

For example, `$ python3 budget.py activate <name>`, then if I do `$ python3 budget.py add <amount> <label>` this will get added to my activated budget.json file. I dont want to each time add the argument of which budget file to add data to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables for that.

First set an environment variable with the name of the current object:

On Linux:

```
export CURRNT_OBJECT=<name>
```

On Windows Powershell:

```
$env:CURRNT_OBJECT=<name>
```

And you can access the current object in your python script using:

```
os.getenv("CURRENT_OBJECT")
```

If you want all the interaction to be with your python script, you can set the environment variable in python:

```
os.environ["CURRENT_OBJECT"] = name
```

And use argparse to run this line with the name of the object when you call `python3 budget.py activate <name>`.

Comment: Thanks for the respond! I will try this and get back to you! :)